# ASP.NET Web-API not serializing readonly property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I migrated an API method from a standard MVC action to the new asp.net Web-API beta and suddenly a read only property is no longer serialized (both returning JSON). Is this expected behaviour?

Edit: Added code sample

I have both Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.8 and System.Json 4.0 referenced through nuget packages

```
        public IQueryable<Car> Gets()
        {
             return _carRepository.GetCars();
        }

        public class Car
        {
            public IEnumerable<Photo> Photos
            {
                get { return _photos; }
            }

            public string PreviewImageUrl // No longer serialized
            {
                get
                {
                     var mainImage = Photos.FirstOrDefault(o => o.IsMainPreview) Photos.FirstOrDefault();
                        return mainImage != null ? mainImage.Url : (string.Empty);
                    }
                }
             }
         }
```

Comment: not expected. could you post some code that repros the issue.

Comment: Which JSON serializer are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` that ships with the Beta uses a serializer that does not support read-only properties (since they would not round-trip correctly). We are planning on addressing this for the next realese.

In the mean-time you could use a custom JSON `MediaTypeFormatter` implementation that uses Json.NET (there's one available [here](https://github.com/ChristianWeyer/Thinktecture.Web.Http/tree/master/Thinktecture.Web.Http/Formatters)) instead of the built-in formatter.

**Update:** Also check out Henrik's blog about hooking up a JSON.NET formatter: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx

Comment: Just upgraded to the RC release and this still appears to be an issue.  Just curious if things will change before the final release or should we just not expect read-only properties to be serialized?  Thanks!

Comment: You can try the latest nightly build (instructions: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/353867). Also, make sure that you actually uninstalled the Beta bits from your system. If it's still an issue could you post a repro here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/. Thanks.

Comment: I had uninstalled the beta and installed the RC, but neglected to update my project's packages with nuget, so I was still using beta bits.  After updating, the read-only property is serialized using JSON, but not as XML.  For my purposes, JSON is all I need, so I'm good, but it seems like it should behave the same with XML serialization?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is an expected behavior or not. I would say that this is expected for input parameters (because you cannot set their values) but not for output parameters. So I would say this is a bug for an output parameter. And here's an example illustrating the issue:

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Prop1 = "prop1 value";
        Prop2 = "prop2 value";
        Prop3 = "prop3 value";
    }

    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public string Prop3 { get; protected set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public Product Get(int id)
    {
        return new Product();
    }
}
```

Request:

```
api/products/5
```

Result:

```
{"Prop1":"prop1 value","Prop2":"prop2 value"}
```

So if the property doesn't have a public setter it is not serialized which doesn't seem normal as the `Product` class is used as output in this case.

I would suggest opening a connect ticket so that Microsoft can fix this before the release or at least tell that this is by design.