# Read-only model property not serialized in Web API

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

As per the title, I'm seeing that my read-only model properties are not serialized in my Web API project.  MVC 4 Web API, VS2010.

I've seen a multitude of posts like [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381090/asp-net-web-api-not-serializing-readonly-property) that state that the MVC 4 Web API **beta** did not support JSON serializing of read-only properties.  But many additional references stated that the final release used JSON.NET instead of DataContractJsonSerializer so the issue should be resolved.

Has this issue been resolved or not?  If not, am I forced to put in fake setters just to get serialization?

---

Correction, it **does** seem to work with JSON (sorry!), but XML exhibits the problem.  So same question as before but in the context of XML serialization.

Comment: Note: this will work with Json.Net ONLY if the readonly property is initialized from the constructor and it's the only available constructor. In other cases you'll need a workaround

Comment: Joanna, I think he's referring to get-only properties without setters, not readonly fields.

Comment: Yes, by a read-only property I mean one without a setter.  It could of course be backed by a read-only variable or constant, but that is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default JSON serializer is now Json.NET. So readonly property serialization should work without you having to do anything at all.

For XML, in 4.5 we added this flag to the DataContractSerializer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializersettings.serializereadonlytypes.aspx

You should be able to write something like this:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SetSerializer(myType, new DataContractSerializer(myType, new DataContractSerializerSettings() { SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true });
```

Place this code in a function called by `GlobalConfiguration.Configure` in the `Application_Start`. By default this would be `WebApiConfig.Register()`.

Comment: Sorry, when I saw it missing in the default XML output I thought it was the same problem in the JSON.  Any ideas on the XML issue?

Comment: Any solution that is available in .NET 4 & VS 2010?

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of a good one for you. I think the best you can do in 4.0 is add private setters and mark the type/property with [DataContract]/[DataMember] and see if that works for you. Public setters would work too.

Comment: Just to add, `DataMember` will not help in .net4 and vs 2010: still the class will be serialized using json even if xml was requested.