# How do I configure the Web API XML serializer to serialize read-only properties for all classes?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have a new Web API solution and I've encountered a problem with the default XML serializer. We were hoping to use read-only properties on all of our response objects via an abstract base class, doing something like this (obviously simplified and genericized):

```
[DataContract]  
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    private MyEnumType? myValue = null;

    [DataMember]
    public bool Prop1
    {
        get { return this.myValue.HasValue; }
    }
}
```

JSON.net will happily serialize the read-only property but the XML serializer will not (even if they're decorated with `[DataMember]`). The API needs to work for XML and JSON responses.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14463089/1812515) provides a nice solution to force the read-only property serialization for a specific class. However, I would like to serialize read-only properties on all classes by default. Is there a way to configure the default DataContractSerializer to do this or do I need to explicitly define the DataContractSerializer for each class I use? Alternatively, is this something that I should even be attempting (i.e., is there a best practices reason that serialization of these properties is disabled by default)?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462960/read-only-model-property-not-serialized-in-web-api/?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, that answer provides a way to override the default serialization behavior for a single class. I would like to override the default serialization behavior for all classes. This may or may not be easily done, but that's why I asked the question.

Comment: Then I would suggest you clarify your question. Among other things, your posted code is more complicated than necessary to illustrate the problem. I just edited your title, which may give you a start in that direction.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I believe that I have edited the question to be more explicit. Please let me know if it is still ambiguous or there are other changes I should make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded in enabling this functionality, at least partially. It's not as straight-forward as I would like, but it does the job. I extended the `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` and overrode the protected method `GetSerializer(Type type, object value, HttpContent content)` .  Adapting the Web API source on [CodePlex](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/XmlMediaTypeFormatter.cs) I was able to get to the level where I could set the options for the default serializer.

```
public class BetterXmlMediaTypeFormatter : XmlMediaTypeFormatter
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> serializerCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>();

    protected override object GetSerializer(Type type, object value, HttpContent content)
    {
        return this.GetSerializerForType(type);
    }

    protected override object GetDeserializer(Type type, HttpContent content)
    {
        return this.GetSerializerForType(type);
    }

    private static object CreateDefaultSerializer(Type type, bool throwOnError)
    {
        Exception exception = null;
        object serializer = null;
        try
        {
            new XsdDataContractExporter().GetRootElementName(type);
            serializer = new DataContractSerializer(type, new DataContractSerializerSettings() { SerializeReadOnlyTypes = true });
        }
        catch (Exception caught)
        {
            exception = caught;
        }

        if (serializer == null && throwOnError)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to create the serializer for type " + type.Name, exception);
        }

        return serializer;
    }

    private object GetCachedSerializer(Type type, bool throwOnError)
    {
        object serializer;
        if (!this.serializerCache.TryGetValue(type, out serializer))
        {
            serializer = CreateDefaultSerializer(type, throwOnError);
            this.serializerCache.TryAdd(type, serializer);
        }

        return serializer;
    }

    private object GetSerializerForType(Type type)
    {
        Contract.Assert(type != null, "Type cannot be null");
        object serializer = this.GetCachedSerializer(type, true);
        if (serializer == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        return serializer;
    }
```

Then I re-configured the Web API to use this formatter for XML requests.

```
    private static void UseBetterXmlFormatter(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.Formatters.Add(new BetterXmlMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.Formatters.Add(new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());
    }
```

This worked beautifully until I needed to *deserialize* an object with read-only properties. My controller methods were receiving a null object every time. After tedious debugging, I discovered that the read-only properties were causing this problem. Reluctantly, I simply resorted to empty `private set` methods on each property, with a *very* explicit comment.

```
public bool Prop1
{
    get { return this.myValue.HasValue; }
    // HACK: Do nothing in the set. It is only present to enable XML serialization.
    private set { }
}
```

I'm still not satisfied with the inelegance of this solution, but it works well enough to ship.

I think that deserializing objects with read-only properties shouldn't really be a difficult problem to solve, but I'll have to leave that problem for another day.